# OAuth2 : redirect_uri post LinkedIn & Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, google-plus, linkedin-api

I'm performing the server side oAuth2 flow.

I noticed that google has added a cool feature for their oAuth2 signin API which is `redirect_uri=postmessage` so we don't show the real redirect_uri on the browser url bar and the `authorization code` won't be included in the redirect url.

For linkedin, when the users accepts to share his personal data with the app, the response url looks like :

`http://dev.localhost.com:8080/auth/linkedin?code=xxxxxxxxxxx&state=yyyyyyyyyyyyy`

it's the same for `Google` unless we replace the real `redirect_uri` by `postmessage`.

If the redirect_uri + the response code is set in the url Every malicious script could be able to retrieve the returned `code` from the url and perform its own authentications.

So, is there any way to hide the return parameters and the redirect_uri for LinkedIn and Facebook ?

Comment: _“Every malicious script could be able to retrieve the returned code from the url and perform its own authentications”_ – no they can not, because exchanging the `code` for an access token requires your app secret. (And if you have that exposed to 3rd party scripts, then you have bigger problems already.)

Comment: I understand. This clarifies things, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn and Facebook are not vulnerable to malicious scripts accessing the redirect_uri.

Assuming you use the recommended `response_type=code` both APIs require you make a request from your server that includes your API secret and the `code` value in order to get the users token. LinkedIn describes this in [Exchange Authorization Code for a Request Token](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#accesstoken) and Facebook describes this in [Exchanging code for an access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#exchangecode).

Additional security with Facebook can enabled with requiring that [every request be signed with your API secret](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests). Additional protection in general can be had by using a strong [Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) to help prevent malicious scripts from running in the first place. And be sure to host your site exclusively over TLS to prevent your own JavaScript from being modified.

Comment: I understand, that was instructive. Thank you!